# Having an issue using Hibernate/JPA custom queries

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

first time poster here. I am having an issue using a custom finder query with spring/jpa.
I have a simple ecommerce project using ORM with 4 tables in database. Customer accounts, list of products, current cart, and transaction history.
The problem I am having is using the specific finder methods.
In order to ensure the value of each Order No be incrementally inserted upon checkout(save and flush a list of all items in current cart to transaction history) I have to find that specific value by account Id, and ++ for every checkout, before setting it to save and Flush.

Can someone point out what I am doing wrong?

cart Dao with finder methods:

```
public void deleteAllByAccountId(int accountId);

public void deleteByBookIdAndAccountId(int bookId, int accountId);

public List<CartEntity> findAllByAccountId(int accountId);

@Query ("SELECT MAX(orderNo) FROM current_cart WHERE accountid = :#{customer_accounts.accountid}")
public CartEntity findByAccountId(@Param("accountid") int accountId);
```

cart Entity:

```
@Table(name = "current_cart")
 public class CartEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) // Id is the primary auto generated key
@Column(name ="orderno")
private int orderNo;

@Column(name = "accountid")
private int accountId;

@Column(name = "cost")
private int bookCost;

@Column(name = "quantity")
private int quantity;

@Column(name = "booktitle")
private String bookTitle;

@Column(name = "bookid")
private int bookId;





@Table(name = "customer_accounts")
 public class AccountEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) // Id is the primary auto generated key
@Column(name = "accountid")
private int accountId;

@Column(name = "email")
private String email;

@Column(name = "password")
private String password;

@Column(name = "firstname")
private String firstname;

@Column(name = "lastname")
private String lastname;
```

checkout logic:

```
public void Checkout(int accountId) {

    List<CartEntity> FetchedCartEntities = cartDao.findAllByAccountId(accountId);

    List<TransactionHistoryEntity> transactionsToCopy = new ArrayList<TransactionHistoryEntity>();
    for (CartEntity cartEntity : FetchedCartEntities) {
        TransactionHistoryEntity transaction = new TransactionHistoryEntity();

        BeanUtils.copyProperties(cartEntity, transaction);

        transactionsToCopy.add(transaction);
    }
    transactionHistoryDao.saveAllAndFlush(transactionsToCopy);

    cartDao.deleteAllByAccountId(accountId);
}
```

Thank you guys

Comment: `SELECT MAX(orderNo) FROM...` returns a single numeric value, but the method signature indicates it returns a `CartEntity`.  The method return type and what the query returns are not compatible.

Comment: Yeah I managed to get it with this 
@Query(value = "SELECT max(orderNo) FROM current_cart", nativeQuery = true)
 int getMaxOrderNo();